# mysql select removes + sign from varchar

Tags: php, mysql

I have noticed a strange behavior in mysql, and cannot understand why it happens.

I have a varchar field, storing a telephone number, like: '+12345677890'.

When I retrieve the data from PHP, it removes the + sign, and only returns '12345677890'.

There is not much code to show. Basically when I fetch the results, + is already removed:

```
$ret = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

why this happens? Can I get the value exactly like it is stored in the database?

Update: the error was in a later processing, calling json_decode($ret['phone'], true). This was removing the + sign. I apologize for not noticing, and thank you all for your comments

Comment: show code as well

Comment: PHP assume it's a number. Add a cast in front when you get your variable `(string)$mysqlResult->$row['phone_col']`. I has same issue when I get a number with a leading 0 store as a string.

Comment: casting is not a solution. some numbers have +, some don't

Comment: When you use other client (e.g: MySql workbench) do you get the same behavior, or it's only PHP ?

Comment: in the database is stored correctly. I can see it from HeidiSQl client. only happens in PHP.

Comment: `some numbers have +, some don't` - this does not mean that casting wouldn't work

Comment: if i add + to all, i will be displaying wrong values for all that don't have a +

Comment: There's multiple places where this implicit casting can occur. You need to share your query as well as how you use the result.

Comment: try `var_dump` of your result to see what type PHP put to your value

Comment: btw, casting will no add a + in front of your value...it's only a way to tell PHP which type to use for variable

Comment: Just tried something like this - varchar field with same value.  Fetch using PDO and there is no problem with the value returned - "+12345677890"

Comment: the error was later, in json_decode($ret['phone'], true). It was removing the + sign. I apologize for not noticing, and thank you all for your comments.

Comment: Why 5 upvotes ..?